# Laravel initial router, how to pass the controller?

Tags: php, laravel, router

Mrs. good morning I'd like to config my Laravel initial route, to works on the /, I don't know how I can to do to use the controller.

I use at this moment redirecting my initial route to /start route, but I'd like to use on / only.

See my router below.

```
Route::controller("Start");
Route::controller("Search");
Route::controller("Contact");

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return Redirect::to("start");
});
```

I'd like to make:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make("start.index");
});
```

And pass the Start.php controller to this view, it's possible?

Can somebody help me with?

Comment: Route::get('/', 'StartController@index'); should be working right, or is a solution you are especially avoiding?

Comment: @Damien, thank you, thats exactly what I need!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Route::get('/', 'StartController@index');
```

looks like what you're after: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing

You can also call it using an array, to pass additional params:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'start', 'uses' => 'StartController@index']);
```

Comment: Thank you @Damien, helps a lot!