# Laravel 5.1 Using controllers as a route

Tags: php, laravel

I use the Laravel 3 and I'm start a project using Laravel 5.1, a lot of things changes, include some way that I use to make my routes.

I like to implemente my routes using my controllers, like the code below:

```
Route::controller("Search");
Route::controller("Contact");
Route::controller("Login");

Route::get('/', "Inicio@index");
```

But it's not works in Laravel 5.1, someone knows if this way changes or not exists more?

Thank you.

Comment: Check documentation https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing

Comment: What's wrong with the SAME question you asked yesterday, and the accepted answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859953/laravel-initial-router-how-to-pass-the-controller

Comment: Describe one of those controllers, please.

Comment: Is a different question my friend, Yesterday I ask how to use a controller in a  initial route, this question is how to use Route::controller() in laravel 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Route::resource()` method, the first parameter will be the URL prefix and 2nd will be the controller name, like this:

```
Route::resource('admin-panel', 'AdminController');
```

Now, say if your controller have a method named login, the URL generated will be `admin-panel/login`. There's also an optional 3rd parameter, check [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) for details.